# Why when I create new xml layout the control in palette change to old version of control in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, palette, android-version, android-controls

[image]

[image]

First I create my project that `minSdkVersion="13"` and `targetSdkVersion="15"`. But when I create new xml for layout, the control of the Palette at the left side show the old version of control. And When it's launch in emulator(version 4.0.3) it's show the style of old control too. how can I change the control of the palette to the new version?

Comment: u have to update ur eclipse once then it wil show u new version

Comment: My eclipse is update all the time when its notify me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this generally happens when initially while creating project you had some other target but later you changed in manifest , you need to change targetsdkversion in project.properties file to "15" .

Comment: I go to, right click on project and click Properties > Android > in the Project Build Target its already check the API level 15.

Comment: You do not have to take this path rather you have to edit the project.properties file of your android project.

Comment: How can I edit project properties. can you show me? best regards, thanks

Comment: In your Android project hierarchy there is a file with the name project.properties. Open this file and check this line:
target=android-15 in case it is different change it